# ASP.NET core JWT Token Validation fails on same origin

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm writing an ASP.NET core (2.2) application with angular Web client. For authentication I use JWT Token validation: an "Login" endpoint issues the JWT token which is then presented in the `Authorization: Bearer xxxxx` header.

Everything works fine when the ASP.NET app and the Web client are run independently, i.e. when I start the ASP.NET app in Visual studio and run the Web client using `ng serve` on a different port.

When I copy the compiler web client into the `wwwroot` directory, the JWT token validation fails.

The Login call still succeeds and returns a JWT token. But the next calls with the token in the `Authorization` header fail. The log only gives:

> Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No
>   SecurityTokenValidator available for token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI.....

The server code is the same in both cases, the only change is the "`<base>` tag in the client's `index.html` (since it is served from a "webapp" subpath withn the asp.net app)

As far as I can tell from monitoring the network requests, the header and token are sent correctly. The only differenc is, that the browser is issuing an additional "OPTIONS" request, when the client is run from a different port (due to CORS, I assume, but this part works well, Cors is enabled).

JWT Signing secret, audience, issuer etc are set and the same in both cases.

Is there any other mechanism for JWT Token validation in place that would explain this behavior?

Comment: could you share some code? I am facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and discovered it was related to how the token was added to the header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

I noticed that in this way the token contained " (double quotes) and therefore rejected.
I did this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.Replace("\"", "")}");
```

and worked, not the cleanest solution though :(.
Hope it helps